# Searching for a Twitter API v.1.1 jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, twitter

Can anyone recommend a new Twitter plugin for jQuery.

I was using jquery.liveTwitter - but now Twitter have changed their API this no longer works.

Any recommendations much appreciated.

Comment: I looked into this recently and decided to just use the default REST api from twitter. It's pretty straight forward, https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

Comment: BTW *Twitter have changed their API or something*. they've changed to v1.1 and retired version 1 as it has security flaws: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1

Comment: Why close? There is a clear question here and an answer to the question. This kind of stuff helps people who search for a solution to their requirenments. There is no "what is the best solution?" in the question. It is a simple how can I do X along with valid answers.

Answer (score 5):

[Tweet JS](https://github.com/StanScates/Tweet.js-Mod) makes use of 1.1 version of the API, rather than the deprecated 1.0